# Calling a function on Pandas datetime serie items for filtering

Tags: python, pandas

```
                 Date_Time     Open     High      Low    Close    Up  Down
0      2018-03-20 17:01:00  2723.25  2724.50  2723.25  2723.75   372   345
1      2018-03-20 17:02:00  2723.75  2724.25  2723.50  2724.00   127    49
2      2018-03-20 17:03:00  2724.00  2724.00  2723.75  2723.75    55    11
3      2018-03-20 17:04:00  2724.00  2724.50  2724.00  2724.00   105    25
...
```

I would like to filter the data above so that every row where time is not between 15:00:00 and 17:00:00 is excluded.

I've tried this:

```
df.loc[df.Date_Time.time() > time(15, 0) & df.Date_Time.time() < time(17, 0)]
```

Naturally, this won't work since he tries to call `time()` on a Pandas Series rather than its elements.

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'time'

So, I've figured I could apply a lambda function:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x['Date_Time'].time() > time(15, 0))
```

But this doesn't work either.

> KeyError: ('Date_Time', 'occurred at index Date_Time')

This too:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.Date_Time.time() < time(15, 0))
```

Doesn't work, and I really don't understand why I'm getting a different error.

> AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'Date_Time'",
>   'occurred at index Date_Time')

Is this possible to do in just one line? Or do I have to iterate over the whole serie "manually"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in `pandas` you can check with [`between_time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html)

```
df.set_index(['Date_Time']).between_time('15:00:00', '17:00:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I ignore, using `axis=1` seems to solve the problem.

```
filter = df.apply(lambda x: x['Date_Time'].time() > time(15, 0) and x['Date_Time'].time() < time(17, 0), axis=1)
```

I could then just call `df.loc[filter]`

Comment: Using the built-in `between_time` function as @Wen-Ben mentioned is much more efficient than using `df.apply`.

Comment: Off course, will accept his answer (as soon as I can) as it's way better. Just thought I'd post why my original code wasn't working, just for reference.